# How can I solve this issue for the login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise-token-auth

Hi Everyone I will appreciate if someone can help me with this error:
I'm building a ruby on rails app using Devise Gem.

```
                                         --Error--

undefined method `current_sign_in_at' for #<User id: 1, email: "abe@gmail.com", created_at: "2022-04-29 23:08:34.796522000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-04-29 23:08:34.796522000 +0000">

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 else
        match = matched_attribute_method(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end
    ruby2_keywords(:method_missing)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the issue is `undefined method current_sign_in_at`.  So where is `current_sign_in_at` defined?

Comment: you have to configure your `User` model and add additional database columns that devise is using https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#getting-started `current_sign_in_at` is used by `trackable` module.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I have another problem with the delete link_to mehtod, it works with button_to though

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your migrations ?

To make the current_sign_in_at method available for your User model you should uncomment this line before doing your migrations. Then redo your data base (that would delete your existing  data).

[image]

if you don't want to lose your data, you can add it via a new migration instead if needed.

execute `rails generate migration AddCurrentSignInAtToUser`
and inside of the new file add :

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
  end
```

I haven't tested this last option but it should normally work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I have another problem with the delete link_to mehtod, it works with button_to though